# SQL query to select strings that contain a "Unit Separator" character

Tags: mysql, sql, select, character-encoding, ascii

I have table like this
[image]

I want get those record which content Unit Separator
[image]

I have try many things but not getting result.I try with `char(31)` and `0x1f` and many other ways but not getting desired result.This is my query which i try

```
SELECT * FROM `submissions_answers` WHERE `question_id`=90 AND `answer` like '%0x1f%'
```

How can i do this? Please help me..

Comment: I think you need to use the hexadecimal notation outside of quotes, that's what http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html suggests. Try `... LIKE CONCAT('%', 0x1f, '%')` or `... LIKE CONCAT('%', x'1f', '%')`

Comment: What is the characterset of that database column? Is that the same as the characterset of the client? If not, there may be some characterset translation going on. To figure out what that character is stored in the database, I'd use the HEX function.

Comment: @spencer7593 column type is text and characterset is  utf8mb4_unicode_ci for answer column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT * FROM submissions_answers WHERE question_id=90 AND instr(answer,char(31))>0
```

The keyword here being the `INSTR` MySQL function, [which you can read about here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr). This function returns the position of the first occurrence of substring (`char(31)`) in the string (`answer`).

Comment: could you explain what `INSTR` does and how it solves the problem?

Comment: @Martin: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr

Comment: @BillKarwin most StackOverflow questions would not be here if people looked in the manual, I can and do quite easily research the manaul but I wanted Luis to add a sentence or two describing what he has done, as code only answers are fairly unhelpful and don't convey any learning, as to *why* this code works

Comment: @Martin, fair enough. I assumed you were asking because you were one of the many people who don't think to look in documentation.

Comment: @Luis Siquot I try your query it's work but when i try in this it not work-"SELECT * FROM submissions_answers WHERE ROUND ( (LENGTH(answer) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( answer,char(31), '') ) ) / LENGTH(char(31)) ) > 2".

Comment: `LENGTH(char(31))` acts as a fixed constant equal to 1. (the length of one char is 1) so you always divide by one (not relevant to the query)
`REPLACE ( answer,char(31), '')` will remove all 31's chars, so when you substract the length of the field minus the length of the replaced string, what you got is the total number of 31's chars in the string.
After that you compare against 2. Well, if you have more than two 31's chars on the field, then you will see the record.
Please, what records do you want to see?

Comment: please run this query to have debuging info:
SELECT LENGTH(answer),LENGTH(REPLACE(answer,char(31),'')), REPLACE(answer,char(31),'')
FROM submissions_answers 
WHERE instr(answer,char(31))>0
LIMIT 10

Comment: _(playing devil's advocate)_ Think of a "code only" answer as hints of what to look up.  (`instr` and `char` in this case.)  Then think of it as a lesson in where to look in the reference manual.  In the long run, this will do them in better stead than having the details spoon fed to them.

Comment: @RickJames I think that specific questions should be answered with short and specific answers, because OPs do not detect which is the generic case that covers its problem.  And If you want (as the one which answers) you can keep track on the issue until OP is full convinced.  Sorry about my english

Answer (score 6):

#### Problem

The expression you tried won't work because `answer LIKE '%0x1f%'` is looking for a string with literally `'0x1f'` as part of it - it doesn't get converted to an ASCII code.

#### Solutions

Some alternatives to this part of the expression that *ought* to work are:-

1. `answer LIKE CONCAT('%', 0x1F, '%')`
2. `answer REGEXP 0x1F`
3. `INSTR(answer, 0x1F) > 0`

#### Further consideration

If none of these work then there may be a further possibility. Are you sure the character seen in the strings is actually `0x1F`? I only ask because the first thing I tried was to paste in ␟ but it turns out MySQL see this as a decimal character code of 226 rather than 31. Not sure which client you are using but if the `0x1F` character is in the string, it might not actually appear in the output.

#### Demo

Some tests demonstrating the points above: [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/124c5/6)

Comment: column type is text and characterset is utf8mb4_unicode_ci for answer column.

Comment: as i look your sql demo it's look good but when i try "SELECT * FROM submissions_answers WHERE ROUND ( (LENGTH(answer) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( answer,REGEXP 0x1F, '') ) ) / LENGTH(REGEXP 0x1F) ) > 2" it's not work

Comment: `REGEXP 0x1F` doesn't make sense on its own - [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#idm139954443197632) is an operator that takes the form `expression REGEXP pattern` and returns a boolean indicating whether the specified pattern was found in the expression. Try this instead: `ROUND ( (LENGTH(answer) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( answer, 0x1F, '') ) ) / LENGTH(0x1F) )`. But think it should be `> 1` rather than `> 2` unless you looking for two such characters in the answer? See [this updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/124c5/6) which also addresses your first comment.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way...

```
SELECT * FROM `submissions_answers`
    WHERE `question_id`=90
      AND HEX(`answer`) REGEXP '^(..)*1F'
```

Explanation of the regexp:

- `^` - start matching at the beginning (of `answer`)
- `(..)*` -- match any number (`*`) of 2-byte things (`..`)
- then match `1F`, the hex for US.

Comment: I do +1 your answer as the most creative (unorthodox)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the answer column into a HEX value, and then look for values containing that hex string.

```
SELECT * FROM `submissions_answers`
WHERE HEX(`answer`) LIKE '%E2909F%'
```